# Installed MongoDb on Ubuntu, says its not installed

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Installed MongoDb on Ubuntu following the step by step instructions on the site
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/
I receive the following error when I try and run mongo. "The program 'mongo' is currently not installed."

Yet it is in the directory.

```
test@MongoDb1:~$ mkdir -p mongodb
test@MongoDb1:~$ ls

mongodb      mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.5.4.tgz

test@MongoDb1:~$ cp -R -n mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.5.4/ mongodb
test@MongoDb1:~$ cd mongodb
test@MongoDb1:~/mongodb$ ls

mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.5.4

test@MongoDb1:~/mongodb$ cd mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.5.4/
test@MongoDb1:~/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.5.4$ ls

bin  GNU-AGPL-3.0  README  THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES

test@MongoDb1:~/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.5.4$ cd bin/
test@MongoDb1:~/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.5.4/bin$ ls

bsondump  mongodump    mongoimport  mongorestore  mongotop
mongo     mongoexport  mongooplog   mongos
mongod    mongofiles   mongoperf    mongostat

test@MongoDb1:~/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.5.4/bin$ mongo

The program 'mongo' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install mongodb-clients

test@MongoDb1:~/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.5.4/bin$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see preferred way to install mongodb and all it's dependencies on Ubuntu at [10gen installation doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), add 10gen mongodb public GPG key and:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen
```

Comment: But it doesn't support for 32 bit.

Answer (score 5):

It says it is not installed because:

```
test@MongoDb1:~/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.5.4/bin$ mongo
```

Makes the shell search the OS `$PATH` to find matching programs. Since you downloaded from the internet and extracted it you actually need:

```
test@MongoDb1:~/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.5.4/bin$ ./mongo
```

So that it searches the current directory for the program. Or you can add it to the `$PATH` if you want.

I am unsure if official repos have the unstable edition, as denoted by odd version numbers, i.e. `2.5.x`.